# BST method returns Segfault

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am writing a method to check if a given tree is a BST using the inorder traversal method. On executing this method, I get a segfault. Can someone help me correct it?

here, maximum stores the largest value in the BST, and k is initialized to  0. The BST is assumed to have unique positive values. isNull(root) checks if the current node is a null node or not.

```
bool check(BstNode* root)
{

    if (root->data==maximum) return true;
    isNull(root);

    check(root->left);

    if (root->data>k) 
    {
         k=root->data;

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    check(root->right);
}
```

Comment: Maybe root is null.  Did you try running your code in the debugger?

Comment: Move `isNull(root);` before that first `if(root->data...)...;`. You need to check if it is NULL before you can access its data.

Comment: @Jeribo tried doing that. No good

Comment: @AmirAfghani I've checked the code for regular inorder traversal and it seems to be working fine . I haven't run it in the debugger

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar Can you please show us `isNull()` function? By the look of it you check for NULL but do nothing if it actually is NULL. You may want  to try replacing it with something like this `if(isNull(root)) return false;`

Comment: @Jeribo void isNull(BstNode* root)
{
 if (root==NULL) return ;
 
}

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar There is your problem. You check root node for NULL in a function that does not return anything. Your `isNull()` function is not working as you intended. Either change it to return `bool` value and check that or simply replace that function call in `check()` function with condition `if(root == NULL) return false;`

Comment: I made some other changes to the code and now it's up and  running. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you call check(root->left) and check(root->right), I suppose you need to add sth to determine the left and the right branch is null or not. In your code, you just assume that there is sth in left and right branch and call the check function. I think that's the main reason.

Comment: I do that in a separate function isNull

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar Just calling `isNull(root)` isn't going to do anything. You have to use an overarching if statement that checks `isNull(root)`. If it is false then you can run the code that dereferences `root`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to specify the maximum value. [An elegant solution can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can do this.

One is top-down approach, first check if current node is valid,  if so, then check two subtree. This is very intuitive. you can find the code from [@lerman's post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree):

```
struct TreeNode {
    int data;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
};

bool isBST(TreeNode *node, int minData, int maxData) {
    if(node == NULL) return true;
    if(node->data < minData || node->data > maxData) return false;

    return isBST(node->left, minData, node->data) && isBST(node->right, node->data, maxData);
}

if(isBST(root, INT_MIN, INT_MAX)) {
    puts("This is a BST.");
} else {
    puts("This is NOT a BST!");
}
```

The other way is a bottom-up approach: first check left substree then right substree and check current tree at last. below is the code for this approach.

```
bool isValidBST(TreeNode *root) {
        int mmin, mmax;
        return helper(root, mmin, mmax);
    }

    bool helper(TreeNode* root, int& mmin, int& mmax) {
        if(!root) {
            mmin = INT_MAX;
            mmax = INT_MIN;
            return true;
        }
        int leftmin, leftmax, rightmin, rightmax;
        if(!helper(root->left, leftmin, leftmax))
            return false;
        if(!helper(root->right, rightmin, rightmax))
            return false;
        if(root->val > leftmax && root->val < rightmin) {
            mmin = min(min(leftmin, rightmin), root->val);
            mmax = max(max(leftmax, rightmax), root->val);
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
```

You might notice that the first approach is pre-order traversal and the second approach is post-order traversal. inorder traversal in inappropriate here because it conflicts with the definition of BST.